# Use only certain layers of pretrained torchvision network

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, object-detection

I'm trying to use only certain layers in a pretrained torchvision Faster-RCNN network initialized by:

```
model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
model.eval()
```

This works. However, passing `model.modules()` or `model.children()` into an `nn.Sequential` yields an error. Even passing the whole model leads to errors, e.g.

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential(*model.modules())
model.eval()
# x is a [C, H, W] image
y = model(x)
```

leads to

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

and

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential(*model.children())
model.eval()
# x is a [C, H, W] image
y = model(x)
```

leads to

```
TypeError: conv2d(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not tuple
```

This confuses me because I have modified other PyTorch pretrained models like that in the past. How can I use the FasterRCNN pretrained model to create a new (pretrained) model that uses only certain layers, e.g. all layers but the last one?

Comment: @Shai I would like to remove the RoI-pooling layers, so keep everything before the first RoIHead. In other words: I want to have the two Faster-RCNN stages as two separate networks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike other simple CNN models, it is not trivial to convert an R-CNN based detector to a simple `nn.Sequential` model. If you look at the functionality of R-CNN ([`'generalized_rcnn.py'`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py)) you'll see that the output features (computed by the FCN backbone) are not just passed to the RPN component, but rather combined with the input image and even with the targets (during training).

Therefore, I suppose if you want to change the way faster R-CNN behaves, you'll have to use the base class [`torchvision.models.detection.FasterRCNN()`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/detection/faster_rcnn.py) and provide it with different roi pooling parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I now had a look at the generalized_rcnn.py and copied the forward-pass code to adjust it. It solved my problem.

Comment: @TheWaveLad make sure you are able to load the pre-trained parameters after your change. You might need to tweak the loaded `state_dict`.